# How do I implement this SQL query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this delicious SQL query here that im trying to figure out how to implement in rails using their active record methods ==> .select() .where() ect...

`SELECT
  topics.id
FROM topics
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM votes
    WHERE votes.topic_id = topics.id
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@topics = Topic.where("not exists (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE votes.topic_id = topics.id)")
```